# How to activate / enable the process notification feature in API Monitor?

Tags: apimonitor

[API Monitor](http://www.rohitab.com/apimonitor) has a feature to automatically watch for a new process starting and ask if you want to monitor it. However I have not been able to get this to actually work. The only option in the program I can find which seems to be related is the File menu "Pause Process Notifications" option. However, this is **disabled** which gives me the impressions that it can't be turned off but also that it is supposed to work automatically "out of the box". But whenever I start a new process, nothing happens.

Specifically I'm referring to the feature described [here](http://www.rohitab.com/discuss/topic/38987-api-monitor-v2-r11-process-detection-and-notification-thread-and-error-highlighting-native-client-server-apis/):

> **Process Notification**
>
> API Monitor intercepts process creation and allows you to select the
> process for monitoring. Each time a process is created by the system,
> a notification window is displayed with options to monitor, skip or
> terminate the process. This is especially useful for monitoring
> processes with a short lifespan or processes that are automatically
> launched in the background. Process Notification can also be used to
> monitor applications such as consent.exe (UAC prompt), which run on a
> different desktop.
>
> The following screenshot shows an example of the Process Notification
> window that is displayed when launching an application that requires
> elevation
>
> [image]

I've tried both the 32-bit and 64-bit versions of API Monitor (Version 2.0 Alpha-r13) running both as regular user and as admin; makes no difference.

How can this feature be activated?

---

The specific reason I'd like to use this feature is that I have process `A` which starts process `B`, and it is `B` I need to monitor. `A` and `B` each run for only a few seconds so I can't manually get it to monitor fast enough.

Answer (score 0):

Finally after reading through API Monitor forums I found some information. Unfortunately (for now at least) it seems the answer is that this feature no longer works (since Windows 8.1).

As posted on http://www.rohitab.com/discuss/topic/40418-process-notification-on-81/?p=10093378

> **rohitabPosted 11 October 2013 - 03:38 AM**
>
> Due to security related changes in Windows 8.1, the Process
> Notifications feature of API Monitor does not work. I will try to
> resolve this issue as soon as possible and post a hotfix.

But a later update in 2014 indicated that it hadn't been fixed yet, and seems not to have been since then either.

It was implied that running in a Windows 7 (or 8.0?) virtual machine might be a workaround, or obviously finding another tool which has this capability.